# Find only those galleries with images

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way in Wordpress to use WP_Query and retrieve posts/galleries that have more than 0  metavalues with the key _gallery_image_ids.

Essentially I don't want to display galleries that have no images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out custom field parameters:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

Should be able to do something to the effect of:

```
$options = array(
    'p' => $post_id,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'key' => '_gallery_image_ids',
        'compare' => 'EXISTS'
    );
);

$query = new WP_Query($options);
```

Note: Requires Wordpress 3.5+

Comment: Problem is that wordpress stores an empty value if you delete the images. So this works if you were to never have added any images, but if you add them, then remove them, it no longer works.